# How to speed up nested loops and list comparisons in python

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences that I'm trying to sort so that each subsequent sentence only introduces one new word (that hasn't been seen in previous sentences) at a time. My program works - but takes forever once I begin feeding in a list of decent size. For someone with no CS training and elementary experience as a programmer, how can I make this faster?

I've searched this issue and read about multiprocessing and vector approaches. Initially, it seems that multiprocessing won't help here because I need to compare each element against each other element anyway, so it doesn't matter. (Is that wrong? If so, how can I begin implementing this approach?) Vector posts were beyond my initial understanding.

```
import operator as op 
def ranker(inputList):
    """
    to sort sentences to introduce only one new word at a time
    """

    knownItems = list()
    knownPieces = list()
    temporaryList = list()

    #grab only the section of the inputList that i want to work with
    for x in inputList:
        temporaryList.append(x[0])

    #loop until the whole inputList has been covered
    while(len(temporaryList) >= 1):
        #print(len(temporaryList))
        localStorageDict = {}
        for x in temporaryList:
            wordStorageArray = x.split() 
            counter = 0 
            for word in wordStorageArray:

                if word not in knownPieces:
                    counter += 1
            localStorageDict[x] = counter


        sortedList = sorted(localStorageDict.items(), key=op.itemgetter(1))
        localStorageDict.clear()
        newKnownItem = sortedList[0][0]
        knownItems.append(newKnownItem)
        newKnownPieceArray = newKnownItem.split()
        for word in newKnownPieceArray:
            if word not in knownPieces:
                knownPieces.append(word)

        temporaryList.remove(newKnownItem)

    print(temporaryList)
    return knownItems


sampleList = [('यह बहुत है।', 0), ('यह एक महानदी है।', 6.738544474393532e-05), ('यह मुमकिन है।', 6.738544474393532e-05), ('यह तस्करों का अड्डा है।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('मिशन कामयाब रहा', 0.00097574127), ('ज़ोकर बहुत बौना था', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह एक टेढ़ा विचार था', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह निराली हरकत थी।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('पर्यटक टूर पर था।', 0.000269897574127), ('पहिया ढीला था।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('प्रदर्शनी हाउसफुल थी।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('वह फुरसत में खेलेंगे।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('मेट्रो भूमिगत है।', 0.000227), ('कढ़ी में बहुत मसाला था।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('मीनार बहुत ऊँची थी।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह एक रेतीला तुफान था।', 0.00026954177897574127), ('यह एक कोरा चेक है', 0.000636119), ('इस उत्पाद में एक खराबी है', 0.0004043126684636119), ('यह एक खोटा सिक्का है', 0.0004043126684636119), ('चरवाहा बहुत चालाक था', 0.0004043126684636119), ('छत पर एक कौआ था', 0.000684636119), ('झाड़ी में एक झींगुर था', 0.000404312668463)]

ranker(sampleList)
```

Comment: You should provide sample input and output. What do the floats mean? Also, since your code actually *works*, this might fit better on Code Review.

Comment: Can you switch to an example in English?

Comment: If the list of known words was sorted, for example in one of the binary search tree structures, you could check a possible new word in log n time instead of n time

Comment: @DaveS how would I check a possible new word? i've now been reading about bst for about a week and practiced sorting a list of numbers. i'm not sure how to begin sorting like i am in the above program though...is that an example of insert? i'm not sure i quite understand what you mean

Comment: You can test whether (word) is already in the tree in roughly log(n) time.  If it isn't there, it is a new word.  You add the new phrase to your list, then insert the new word into your tree.

Comment: I don't understand - why will this be faster if the words in the tree aren't in any particular order?

Answer (score 0):

```
sortedList = sorted(localStorageDict.items(),
                    key=op.itemgetter(1))
```

```
if word not in knownPieces:
```

At a glance, it seems that you are sorting a list and scanning another to check the presence of an item at every iteration.

For the sorting, you may consider instead using a tree data structure, as it only requires going up the branches of the tree when you increment your counter rather than sorting the whole list at every iteration.

As for the item check, consider using a `set()`. It is like a dictionary, but without values associated, and checking if an item is in a set takes (roughly) the same time no matter how many items there are in the set. In fact, a set would simplify the operation a lot as the pattern `if x not in my_list: my_list.append(x)` has the same behavior as simply writing `my_set.add(x)`: if the item is already in the set, it is a no-op. The set will not retain your insertion order though, so if that is a problem, you may use a dictionary instead, and simply have the values set to a placeholder like `True`. I learned from user alec_a that Python 3.7 specs guarantee that the insertion order is retained as long as you do not remove keys from the dictionary.

You may also consider using `Counter` from the `collections` module. It is a dictionary subclass that initializes values to 0 and implements a few more operations such as addition and subtraction:

```
>>> Counter(['hello', 'world']) + Counter(['goodbye', 'cruel', 'world')
Counter({'hello': 1, 'world': 2, 'goodbye': 1, 'cruel': 1})

>>> Counter(['hello', 'world']) - Counter(['goodbye', 'cruel', 'world'])                   
Counter({'hello': 1})
```

Comment: Sets are very different from dictionaries because they are orderless

Comment: Is it a requirement to have the words in a specific order? If so, then OP can have both a list and a set. The list keeps track of the order, the set serves as an index for quick lookup.

Comment: @alec_a, you probably meant that sets are very different from lists rather than dictionaries.

Comment: I was simply addressing your statement that a set is like a dictionary except for no association

Comment: @alec_a well then both dictionaries and sets do not have order inherent to them. If `dict.values` or `dict.items` return objects in the order in which they were inserted, it is purely coincidental and you should not rely on that.

Comment: I thought absolute insertion order was added in Python 3.7?

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I looked a bit into it and it seems though that it comes with caveats, namely that the order is no longer guaranteed as soon as you remove a key from the dict… *\[research intensifies\]*

Comment: I didn’t know that... that kinda breaks it

Comment: @sleblanc i don't quite understand how i can sort with a tree data structure. trees are very new to me, i've read about how to sort a list of numbers but i don't understand how i can do it to sort by word, the way i have above, given my array of sentences, which itself isn't numbered. could you elaborate please?